# Сhange the encoding of project file creation in MS-Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, encoding, utf-8

Is there any way to configure Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 to use utf-8 encoding to create source code files for Python projects?

Python uses utf-8 by default to read and execute script files.
But MSVS creates files in user's current locale encoding by default, which is not very convenient, because we either have to recode files or use deprecated declaration for Python files:`# coding=<locale encoding name>` for interpreter to understand which encoding to use when reading script.

Comment: It looks like it has a source code [utf-8 option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @martineau
This is a compiler option, not an IDE option.

Comment: I'm still on VS2019, but there is no option to specify the default encoding.   You can `File, Save As, Select "Save with Encoding" and choose "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" and then MSVS will detect and use UTF-8 when editing the file.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen
I do, because I didn't see any other way.
I was hoping there was one after all. 
In all IDEs, you can specify the desired default encoding.... but not in MSVS.